# Segoe UI Lock and Unlock Symbol Glyph in AppBar

Tags: javascript, windows-phone, winjs, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm trying to use a glyph from the Segoe UI Symbol font for a Windows Phone 8.1 App but can't get it to work.

On **[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/jj841126.aspx)** page (towards the bottom) it defines a lock and unlock glyph with the characters: U+E1f6 and U+E1f7 respectively.

This is how my appbar is defined on the page:

```
<div id="cmdAppbar" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBar">
    <button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmdLogout',label:'Log Out',icon:'???', selection:'global',tooltip:'Log Out'}"></button>
</div>
```

What do I need to put into the icon declaration? Is it the icon name? or the character code? I've tried "`lock`" and "`Lock`" as the icon name and I've tried `U+E1f6`, `UE1F6` and `&E1F6;`

Any ideas? I know it's probably a very simple answer but I've trawled through MSDN and can't find the correct usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
<button data-win-control="WinJS.UI.AppBarCommand" data-win-options="{id:'cmdLogout',label:'Log Out',icon:'&#xE1F6;', section:'global',tooltip:'Log Out'}"></button>
```

The important bit is `&#xE1F6;`